# android emulator sd card

Tags: android, android-emulator

I want to read all the music files from the sd card but I tried to put the file in several places on the SD card and the program still doesn't find the music on the card. Anyone any suggestions? Where exactly to put the files?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you

http://blog.jayway.com/2009/04/22/working-with-sd-cards-in-the-android-emulator/

Comment: sorry but you did not precise ^^ 
Are you using linux ?

Answer (score 0):

I was just doing that last night :).

In android, the sdcard is mounted on '/sdcard'. I don't have the code here, but it was something like this.

```
public List<String> getMp3Files() {
    File sdcard = new File("/sdcard");
    return getMp3Files(sdcard);
}

private List<String> getMp3Files(File directory) {
    List<String> mp3files = new ArrayList<String>();

    File[] files = directory.listFiles();
    if(files == null) {
        return Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    for( File file : files) {
        if( file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp3")) {
            mp3files.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        } else if ( file.isDirectory()) {
            mp3files.addAll(getMp3Files(file));
        }
    }

    return mp3files;
}
```

it's not optimized AT ALL for mobiles, but it works. And be careful that if you run this code starting on the root folder, it will end up in a infinite loop of folders! (you can always try :D).

Comment: My problem is that I can not put the mp3 files on the sdcard of the emulator. When I use DDMS I have 3 directories data, mnt and system.

Comment: and it only allows me to copy things in the data directory but wherever I copy it, the program won't see it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion :). In DDMS, the sd card is in /mnt/sdcard. Something I found yesterday too, is that usually the file transfer fails if the file bigger than a couple of MB, and the only way to transfer some mp3 files was to drag them from explorer to DDMS. If I either tried to push via DDMS or adb, the file transfer would fail.

Comment: My problem is that to this file I don't have permission to write. Don't you know how I could write to /mnt/sdcard. In the column where it writes the permissions it appears only d--------. Do you have any idea what I could do? thanks for the answer btw. when i do try to write to it I get "Failed to push selection: Read-only file system"